# Visual Studio MySQL Dataset Error

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am trying to add a Dataset to my project in Visual Studio 2015 but i am getting the following error:

"Some updating commands could not be generated automatically. The database returned the following error: You have a usable connection already"

I have added the Oracle MySQL connector already.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround on the MySQL connector forums. Basically, use MySQL Connector version 6.9.8, not 6.9.9. My identical question & answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001594/you-have-a-usable-connection-already-error-in-visual-studio-2015-adding-data-s/39001595#39001595)